# Select all children with the key in array with Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let me start by saiyng that I'm a complete beginner with Android and Firebase too. I'm using a small project to learn booth technologies and I came across with this challenge.

Imagine I have the following Firebase Database structure:

```
{
    "projects": {
        "p01": {
            "name": "Projecto #1",
            "created_at": "2017-01-01 20:00:00",
            "tags": {
                "t01": true,
                "t03": true
            }
        },
        "p02": {
            "name": "Projecto #2",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 02:20:33",
            "tags": {
                "t02": true,
            }
        }
    },
    "tags": {
        "t01": {
            "color": "#000CCC",
            "name": "Nature"
        },
        "t02": {
            "color": "#DD00FF",
            "name": "Technology"
        },
        "t03": {
            "color": "#438DC2",
            "name": "Social"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display a list view with all my projects, and on each row I want to display the title of the project and a list of tags with its background color. That I managed to too, but I think the way I achieved it, its not the best practice.

First I create a value event listener to get all all projects, like this:

```
fbdRef.child("projects").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

And on the `onDataChange` I have a for loop that reads and adds all the projects to an ArrayList, but in that loop I do something first asyncronously. Something like this:

```
for(DataSnapshot tagSnapshot: projectSnapshot.child("tags").getChildren()){
     fbdRef.child("tags/" + tagSnapshot.getKey()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

I'm reading all tags, one by one, and updating its item on ListView, this looks ugly and it may be slow. I really am struggling with noSql concept of Firebase and the best way to structure my databases.

**What is the best way to get all tags content from each project?**

Comment: What part of your JSON does `fbdRef.child("errors")` point to?

Comment: Reading data in a loop is not necessarily slow, since Firebase pipelines the requests over a single connection. See my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: I meant "projects" there, wrong copy @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I'd typically read all tags with `addValueEventListener` on `/tags`, since they are likely to be a limited set. Then I'd read the relevant projects and locally look up the relevant tags. If you wire up the listener correctly, you can still live-reload the tags when they're changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct alternative is to:

```
reference.child("projects").addChildEventListener(...);
```

Then for each child added, or moved, or remove, pass it to the adapter and update the adapter.

Since you probably don't want to handle every situation, there is Firebase-Ui library which provides an adapter to display the list: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

You should also check your data structure since the tags are outside the element itself you are doing 2 queries, you should simply add the "name" and "color" attribute to the `Project` model. The key for structuring data in Firebase is to do it by thinking what the views need. Avoid unnecessary nesting and extra queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About the database structure, if I set the tags on each project, I can reuse them and it make break for some reason. Like the same tag but with different colors. How would you structure this, can you paste a json example of what would be your approach, please?

Comment: I would try something like this:

{
    "projects": {
        "p02": {
            "name": "Projecto #2",
            "created_at": "2017-02-01 02:20:33",
            "tags": {
              "kjwbdwidb": {
                "name": "something",
                "color": "SOME_HEX"
              },
              "kjnwdawnd": {
                "name": "something else",
                "color": "SOME_HEX"
              }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Or maybe something more simple like this:

{
  "projects": {
      "p02": {
          "name": "Projecto #2",
          "created_at": "2017-02-01 02:20:33",
          "tag": "something",
          "color": "YOUR_HEX"
          }
      }
}

BTW, can you mark the question as answered if it is correct, please?